# Would it be possible to have a warm current going up the coast of Labrador and entering into Hudson Bay?

Tags: climate, geography, currents

I need a warm current to pass along the coast of Labrador (I have another one already entering the Saint Lawrence) and enter the Hudson Bay.

That way I would make it somehow like Western Europe with a very nice productive climate, keep the Northeast passage open, weaken Tornado alley (so making the plains even more productive and the Mississippi basin even richer), and decrease dryness of the northern territories so making the prairies go all the way up north.

My question is not that if it would only be possible (as for instance, as a branch of the Gulf Stream if the Labrador current was able to pierce it in the middle), but also how can it be possible without killing the Labrador current (what would catastrophically kill the Grand Banks).

Comment: Problem: You are diverting some heat that winds up making northwestern Europe habitable. Heating Quebec and Manitoba a bit also means cooling Norway and France and Poland and Russia a bit.

Answer (score 3):

No.
There are two parts to the Gulf Stream: the warm part going from the equator through the Gulf of Mexico up to Europe, and the colder part going down from the north back to the equator. Both are important parts. You can't have a current into a bay without an equal amount of water leaving the bay. In most cases, the two currents need a temperature difference to drive the currents.

The entrance to the Hudson Bay is quite shallow and the whole Hudson Bay is also shallow. That means that a warm current going in won't have an equivalent cold current coming out.

The Labrador Current starts on the east side of Greenland, goes around and up the west side of Greenland before coming back down the Labrador coast. A warm current going up would have to break through the Labrador Current to get into the Hudson Bay.